# Equivalent of SAP HANA function workdays_between() in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, hana

I have a requirement where I have to rebuild a SAP HANA view in Snowflake. The view is using `workdays_between()` function in SAP HANA which is used to find work days between two dates based on factory calendar it use `TFACS` table to count the working days. In Snowflake we don't have `workdays_between()` function so please let me how we can use this function in Snowflake to count working days.

I tried to create a UDF in Snowflake but recreating the logic of `workdays_between()` in Snowflake is quite difficult because it counts number of 1 from `TFACS` table based on country code (`IDENT`), year (`JAHR`) and month columns. So please help to create the logic in Snowflake.

TFACS table in SAP:
TFACS table in SAP has various columns like IDENT(Country Code), JAHR(Year), MON01....MON12 working days details for every month.

[TFACS table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tZT6.png)

Data of TFACS Table for country code: IN and year : 2023
Here 1 means working day and 0 means holiday including Saturday and Sunday.

[TFACS table output for country code IN and year 2023](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlpZF.png)

I have to build similar thing in Snowflake. But in Snowflake workdays_between() function is not available please let me know if anyone has any solution.

Comment: This TFACS table is confusing. How do i know which month has which holidays? how does the data look like ? Snowflake is little straight forward date1 - date 2 - holidays like any normal person will do. SAP is written by Einstein so you need to help us.

Comment: TFACS table is a factory calendar table in SAP it has various columns like IDENT(which is country code), JAHR(which is year column) and there is month column MON01.....MON12 for each month of the year. workdays_between() function use this table to find to number of 1's in the month column 1 means working day 0 means holiday including saturday sunday and public holidays. Suppose we have to find working days for India for date between 2023-01-01 and 2023-01-31 then in TFACS table IDENT will be IN and JAHR will be 2023 and then the count of 1's in MON01 column will be no. of working day.

Answer (score 1):

I created a SQL-only solution in Snowflake that mimics the `workdays_between` function in SAP HANA.

The full write-up can be found [here](https://www.lbreddemann.org/sap-factory-calendar-in-snowflake/), but the solution code is this:

```
create view SF_SAP_FACTORY_CALENDAR as (
    with tfacs_pivot as (
        select IDENT, JAHR, MON01 as DAY_FLAGS, '01' as "MONTH" from TFACS UNION ALL 
        select IDENT, JAHR, MON02 as DAY_FLAGS, '02' as "MONTH" from TFACS UNION ALL 
        select IDENT, JAHR, MON03 as DAY_FLAGS, '03' as "MONTH" from TFACS UNION ALL 
        select IDENT, JAHR, MON04 as DAY_FLAGS, '04' as "MONTH" from TFACS UNION ALL 
        select IDENT, JAHR, MON05 as DAY_FLAGS, '05' as "MONTH" from TFACS UNION ALL 
        select IDENT, JAHR, MON06 as DAY_FLAGS, '06' as "MONTH" from TFACS UNION ALL 
        select IDENT, JAHR, MON07 as DAY_FLAGS, '07' as "MONTH" from TFACS UNION ALL 
        select IDENT, JAHR, MON08 as DAY_FLAGS, '08' as "MONTH" from TFACS UNION ALL 
        select IDENT, JAHR, MON09 as DAY_FLAGS, '09' as "MONTH" from TFACS UNION ALL 
        select IDENT, JAHR, MON10 as DAY_FLAGS, '10' as "MONTH" from TFACS UNION ALL 
        select IDENT, JAHR, MON11 as DAY_FLAGS, '11' as "MONTH" from TFACS UNION ALL 
        select IDENT, JAHR, MON12 as DAY_FLAGS, '12' as "MONTH" from TFACS),
     day_point as (
        select tfp.*
                , length(DAY_FLAGS) AS NUM_FLAGGED_DAYS
                ,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "JAHR", "MONTH" ORDER BY "JAHR", "MONTH" )  as FLAG_POINTER
            from tfacs_pivot tfp
                cross join table ( generator (rowcount =>32))  d
     
     )
    select dp.*
            , date_from_parts (JAHR, "MONTH", FLAG_POINTER) as FACTORY_DATE
            , substr(dp.DAY_FLAGS, FLAG_POINTER , 1) as day_marker
            , to_boolean (DAY_MARKER) as IS_WORKING_DAY
        from day_point dp
    where FLAG_POINTER <= NUM_FLAGGED_DAYS);
```

Now I can simply run

```
select FACTORY_DATE, IS_WORKING_DAY from SF_SAP_FACTORY_CALENDAR;
```

to get the information I am after:

```
FACTORY_DATE   IS_WORKING_DAY
2018-01-01     FALSE
2018-01-02     TRUE
2018-01-03     TRUE
2018-01-04     TRUE
2018-01-05     TRUE
2018-01-06     FALSE
2018-01-07     FALSE
2018-01-08     TRUE
...            ...
```

With this view set up, and likely materialised in a production environment, it is only a small additional step to create a `WORKDAYS_BETWEEN` function that mimics the SAP HANA equivalent:

```
create function workdays_between (factory_calendar_id varchar(2), start_date date, end_date date )
    RETURNS INTEGER 
    AS $$
        SELECT count(*) 
        FROM SF_SAP_FACTORY_CALENDAR
        WHERE 
            IDENT = factory_calendar_id
            AND FACTORY_DATE between start_date and end_date
            AND IS_WORKING_DAY = true 
    $$;


SELECT workdays_between ('AU', '2018-02-01', '2018-05-01');

WORKDAYS_BETWEEN ('AU', '2018-02-01', '2018-05-01')
                                                 61
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a Snowflake UDF in Python that can get you the desired results:

```sql
create or replace function workdays_between(
    date1 date, date2 date, country_region string
)
returns number
language python
runtime_version = '3.8'
packages = ('holidays')
handler='x'
as 
$$
from datetime import date, timedelta
import holidays
def x(start_date, end_date, country_region):
    days = (end_date - start_date).days + 1
    if days <= 0:
        return 0

    parsed_country_region = country_region.split('-')
    country = parsed_country_region[0]
    region = (
        parsed_country_region[1]
        if len(parsed_country_region) > 1
        else None
    )
    range_years = range(start_date.year, end_date.year+1)
    holidays_dict = holidays.country_holidays(
       country
       , subdiv=region
       , years=range_years
    )

    weekdays = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

    working_days = [day for day in range(days) if (start_date + timedelta(day)).weekday() in weekdays and
        (start_date + timedelta(day)) not in holidays_dict]
    return len(working_days)
$$
;
```

For example:

```sql
select workdays_between('2022-01-01', '2022-10-10', 'US-CA');

-- 192
```

Related:

- https://medium.com/snowflake/generating-all-the-holidays-in-sql-with-a-python-udtf-4397f190252b

Comment: Hi Felipe, Thanks for your solution it looks fine but when I tried to implement then I found that there is some difference in output compared to SAP function workdays_between() upon analysis I found that python library holiday is not exactly same as TFACS table. Below is one example according to python holiday library 16th January is holiday for US country code but for SAP TFACS table it is a working day.                                                                               Python Output for country code 'US':

Comment: Jan 16 2023 is a federal Holiday in the US. That's why I like the Python Holidays library. I don't know why SAP is wrong. https://www.officeholidays.com/countries/usa/2023

Comment: the factory calendar allows companies to define when their working days are each year. That may or may not be the same as public holidays - it’s up the company to maintain the table.